# is there a function readDir, how to access the value in the other file?

Tags: c#

I divided the code into parts of Main.cs and readDirectory.cs. How to return the result from readDir functions in readDirectory.cs to Main.cs?  Below is readDirectory.cs code

```
class ReadDirectory
{
    public static string[] readDir()
    {

         string textFile = @"C:\Users\Nurgaliev.IA\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Debug\paths.txt";
        string[] lines = null;

        if (File.Exists(textFile))
        { 
           lines = File.ReadAllLines(textFile); 
        }
        return lines;  
    }
```

Comment: in main: `var result = ReadDirectory.readDir()`?

Comment: simply and easily. thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function `readDir()` of  `readDirectory.cs` from `Main.cs`

Try this inside `Main.cs`:

```
string[] TextInFile= ReadDirectory.readDir();
```

As it is static function so just call it directly using its class name.